# git: exclude a directory from "untracked files" without removing it from the repository

Tags: git, filenames, gitignore, vmware-fusion

**tl;dr**:
Is there a way to get Git to permanently exclude all working-copy changes in a subdirectory of a Git repository, from being listed in "untracked files" and "deleted files" in `git status` and friends, **without** removing them from the remote origin?

I'm on a system that unavoidably renames certain files, but they shouldn't be renamed on the repository. I'm not working with those files, but they're cluttering up my `git status` and `git diff` output. Adding them to `.gitignore` solves the untracked files problem, but it still says the files were deleted.

*Long-winded explanation for the curious, and to avoid people saying I shouldn't be asking this question:*

My working copy is in a shared folder that I'm trying to access from both a VM (Ubuntu in VMware Fusion) and the host (Mac OS X); I did the clone on the VM side. The VM's shared folders feature replaces `:` with `&%` in any filename as soon as it's written to the filesystem, and that's how OS X sees it. The problem is, my workplace's Git repository has *hundreds* of mission-critical files with `:` in the filename, all in one big directory. I have no need to edit or use these files or the directory they're all in, but they show up as deletions and untracked files any time I want to use GitX or the command line utilities from the Mac side (which would allow me to do development without using up all my RAM for the VM,). Other than that, git on the Mac sees my other changes correctly, and it would work perfectly except for this one directory. I can't rename the files back to colons, since that's illegal on OS X (and breaks `ls` if you try to `mv` it, FWIW). Any other solution beside the one I mentioned is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Colons are in fact legal characters for filenames accessed through the POSIX API on Mac OS X.  The Finder will display them as slashes, and the terminal will display them as colons.  When I try `touch a:b ; ls` on my Mac OS X computer, it shows a file named `a:b` which appears as `a/b` in the Finder.  So it sounds to me like your VM is doing some unnecessary work there.

Comment: Have you reset the repository after adding the .gitignore?

Comment: @Dietrich: Thanks, that does seem to be the case. What I meant was that the VM is unable to access files with colons in the name.

Comment: @J-16 just tried that, and sadly it shows the same symptoms before and after a reset, from either the Mac or Ubuntu side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to mark paths in a git workspace as "unchanged", so that `git status` and `git diff` will not see that the file/path has been modified.  E.g.:

```
$ echo "default_value=Foo" > local.properties
$ git add local.properties
$ git commit -m'Default local.properties'

$ git update-index --assume-unchanged local.properties
$ echo "default_value=Bar" > local.properties
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Once the "[assume-unchanged](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-update-index.html#_using_8220_assume_unchanged_8221_bit)" bit is set for the path, git will no longer expect any modifications to the file, and will not report any modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm no longer working for the company this project was for, so I can't test your solution. Would it work on an entire directory, though? It's not that the file seemed to have been changed, but that it seemed to have been deleted and another file with the `&%` had been added. I'll gladly accept if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try figuring out a different way to share the files between your VM and your host system, because both Ubuntu and Mac OS X allow colons in filenames.

I do not recommend AFP (the Mac's file sharing protocol), because the Linux client is broken and will map colons to slashes, making files with colons completely inaccessible, because the slashes will be interpreted as directory separators.  (Yes, I filed a bug against afpfs.)

I do not recommend SAMBA either, I suspect the filenames are fairly limited for SAMBA.

But NFS works.  It is very easy to set up on Mac OS X, the server programs are already installed, you just have to edit your exports file (`/etc/exports`, see `man 5 exports`) and turn the server on (`nfsd enable`).  From Linux, mount the NFS share (`mount host:/absolute/path`).  Done.

There are a couple issues you'll need to solve to get this working smoothly.  Ideally, your user ID is identical on both systems -- it is probably 500 on your Mac and 1000 on Ubuntu.  Edit `/etc/passwd` on Linux to fix this and `chown -R username /home/username` afterwards.  (I did the opposite and changed the UID on my Mac to 1000, but my account disappeared from the login window.  C'est la vie.)  Your computer will probably have a gaping security hole unless you're careful with your `exports` file -- remember that NFS is not only unencrypted, but NFS servers *trust* their clients almost completely and do not ask for authentication (unless you use GSS, which is available in NFSv3 and standard in NFSv4, but GSS is a lot of work).

You can also do the opposite -- export NFS from Ubuntu and mount it on the Mac.  Select "connect to server" in the Finder and enter `nfs://host/absolute/path`, it will appear as a volume.